# Using Regex and BeautifulSoup in Python to count number of distinct URLs on a webpage

Tags: python, regex, search, beautifulsoup

I currently have an assignment to create a Python script that could search for the number of unique URLs on a webpage and provide the count. The scope of the assignment is to use regex to search for URLs, so it's in the code regardless of if there may be better alternative methods (e.g. using href tags).

The assumption is that the URL would be enclosed by two quotation marks (e.g.  or ), so I would not need to count cases such as "mtv (http://mtv.com)".

Local file references, e.g. /news, /sports, /rankings would not count as distinct URLs, while arguments to the URL, e.g. ?login=misterT and ?login=missesK would count as two distinct URLs.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import ssl
import sys

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#Ask the user for URL:
url = input('Enter the URL you would like to check: ')

try:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
except:
    print("Cannot access - please check your URL!")
    sys.exit()

#Initialize counter
count = 0

##Search for http, whether or not it is secure, optional www group, any one or more word character after,
##any one word character one or more times(Groups for domain, then .com, .org, .gov, etc.), followed by forward slash, 
##followed by any one word character one or more times,
##followed by a question mark (to account for arguments in URLs), enclosed by double quotes, regardless of case 
def websitecount(url):
    re_flags = ( re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE )
    websites = re.findall('/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/', str(soup), re_flags)

    return len(websites)

#Count the number of unique URLs
print('The count of unique URLs is:', websitecount(url))
```

When I execute the code, I get the error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" on the regex line (websites = re.findall). How could I think about modifying the code to accomplish my desired goal?

Edit:
I've modified the code to use a function, but I still get a returned value of 0. E.g. When I enter the URL for this thread, which should return a value of 4 given the 4 URLs below:

`"http://www.google.com/query?id=232"`
`"http://www.google2.com/id?login=222"`
`"http://www.google3.com/iwow?login=2312"`
`"http://www.mtv.com/id?login=483984"`

Comment: you can use `html.text` directly or change `soup` to `str(soup)`

Comment: The code executes now, but now the count returns a value of zero no matter the URL. How could I think about setting the counter up properly?

Comment: Guys, the url regex with // inside a character class is a clear sign it is not to trust, just like some spam email. Where do you get it from all the time?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not sure what you're referring to...? The regex construction is something I found on another Stack Overflow thread

Comment: I modified the re_flags to only include re.IGNORECASE and modified the regex to include an optional question mark at the end and now the script prints out a count...not sure how I would verify if the count is correct? It prints a count of 239 for this page.